# How to access Library of RabbitMQ with Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am developing an app with Ionic 2 (using TypeScript, not JavaScript) and I am trying to find out which is the best library to use Ionic with RabbitMQ.
Basically, How to access Library of RabbitMQ with Ionic 2

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what you're trying to do with Rabbit.  It seems to me like you'd be best served by exposing RabbitMQ via a Web API using Websockets or Server Sent Events (SSE).  Or possibly via native Push Notifications if you are deploying native.